# Open Mobile camera for barcode scan from web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, camera, mobile-website

i hope you'r all doing well. I am working on a project in which we ask the user to scan a barcode,I want if the user click on a specific button at mywebsite the mobile camera will open to scan the barcode but i am not sure how to open the mobile camera for that purpose, can somebody help me please ? Thanks in advance.
Note : I am not providing the barcode but i just want to open mobile camera to scan any barcode at clicking  button.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on most mobile devices.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

It's essentially an input box like a button. When the user clicks on it, it launches the camera.